# How to access to parent widget on qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, kde-plasma

I have an inherited QTreeWidget (called PackList) class and its parent is a KXmlGuiWindow. 
How can I access to the parent's slots?

I've tried getParent()->mySlot() from the QTreeWidget class but I've got

```
error: no matching function for call to 'PackList::mySlot()'
```

Does anybody know the correct way? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you know the parent's class, you will have to cast parentWidget() to that class and then call your slot. Keep in mind whether or not it's a slot makes no difference in this case. You are just calling a method.

```
((KXmlGuiWindow*)parentWidget())->mySlot();
```

You can make the call without casting by wiring up your signal to the slot.

```
connect( this, SIGNAL(mySignal()), parentWidget(), SLOT(mySlot()) );
```

Lastly, you can use [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-3) to call it if you don't want to cast it. That's probably overkill.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I have used it without typecast `parentWidget())->setEnabled();` and I override the parent's setEnabled function. And then, my modification did not work. well, I realized later that this is so silly mistake, but I think it can be a point many fellows may waste their time. anyway; DO NOT FORGET THE TYPECAST.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

However, you can access the parent widget of a widget with [parentWidget()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qwidget.html#parentWidget).

Then, you should be able to call any public slot :

```
parentWidget()->a_slot();
```

Comment: solved connecting the event in the parent instead than the packList