# Qt access MainWindow from QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a OpenGL widget inside the MainWindow.

[image]

I'd like to access **MainWindow** from its code.

I've tried it with the `qApp->activeWindow()` and `findChild()` combo but it does not work.

The **WidgetOpenGLDraw** constructor looks like:

`WidgetOpenGLDraw::WidgetOpenGLDraw(QWidget* parent):QOpenGLWidget(parent),gl(nullptr){}`

EDIT**1**>

This also crashes: `((MainWindow*)qApp->activeWindow())->fname_here();`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access to parent widget on qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352758/how-to-access-to-parent-widget-on-qt)

Comment: @LogicStuff I'm not doing anything with slots and I've already tried casting the parent argument from my constructor but it did not work.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` maybe?

Comment: @LogicStuff If you meant something like this `(dynamic_cast<MainWindow*>((qApp->activeWindow())))->fname_here();` then it does not work. Did you mean I should try it with the parent constructor argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMainWindow` isn't the parent of `WidgetOpenGLDraw`. `QMainWindow` has `centralWidget()` which is the parent of `WidgetOpenGLDraw`. So this **might** work.

```
MainWindow* mainWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parentWidget()->parentWidget());
if (mainWindow) {
 // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `QWidget* parent` in the constructor is the QMainWindow. Store this as a member and you can access it from your WidgetOpenGLDraw class.

Doesn't sound nice but it should work.